# Sql based on dynamic where condition

Tags: sql

I have a query, in this there are multiple conditions based on parameter

`select a,b,c,d from xyz where 
case p='Closed' then (q-r)=0
case p='Pending' then (q - isnull(r,0) )>0
case P='All' then all records to be display`

It gives Incorrect Syntax near line case

Kindly suggest me any other solution to change *'where condition'* depending on parameter value,

since in given sql, *'where'* condition is depend on parameter p value.

You can see in given syntax, if the parameter value is change, condition also get changed.

In first case if p='Closed' then `select ... where q-isnull(r,0)=0`

if p='Pending' then `select ... where (q - isnull(r,0) )>0`

In first condition it is comparing **'equal to'** condition & in next example it is **'greater than'** zero value.

like in third condition I want to display all records.

Here problem is, 'case' structure is only return a value, not expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple criteria to be evaluated in your case statement then all you have to do is shift them all to before the THEN and return a value that indicates that it passes the check.

For your code, this can be done like so:

```
select a,b,c,d from xyz where 1 =
case p='Closed' and (q-r)=0 then 1
case p='Pending' and (q - isnull(r,0) )>0 then 1
case P='All' then 1
```

Though your syntax doesn't work with SQL Server (I'm not sure what database you're querying). A working version in SQL Server would be:

```
select a,b,c,d from xyz where 1 =
CASE 
    WHEN p='Closed' AND (q-r)=0 THEN 1
    WHEN p='Pending' AND (q - isnull(r,0) )>0 THEN 1
    WHEN P='All' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END
```

Comment: There are multiple conditions based on parameter. In this example  3 different conditions i.e. equal to or greater than or true (1=1.....  

Requested for one complete query for all above criteria

Comment: I've edited my answer to address all your issues. Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks a lot , testing on Sql Server 2008 r2. Last syntax is worked